# Override space data display mode

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I'm trying to run an operator that works only in outliner's Libraries display from the Viewport.

[image]

What I have so far calls the operator but I the console shows me this error:

AttributeError: 'SpaceView3D' object has no attribute 'edit_tree'

Here is the script:

```
class SimpleTest(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "outliner.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "001"

    def execute(self, context):
        for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
            if area.type == 'OUTLINER':
                override = bpy.context.copy()
                override['area'] = area
                override["display_mode"] = ['LIBRARIES']
                bpy.ops.SimpleOperator
                break            
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "outliner.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Export Selected Materials"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        sel_mats = []
        for item in context.selected_ids:
            if item.bl_rna.identifier == "Material":
                sel_mats.append(item.name)
        print(sel_mats)

        txt_name = "Materials_to_be_Replaced 001"
        
        path = bpy.path.abspath("//txt_export\\")
        os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)

        with open(path + txt_name + ".txt", "w") as file:
            file.write(str(sel_mats))

        return {'FINISHED'}
```

Comment: I think you forgot some part of your script ? what's `bpy.ops.SimpleOperator` ?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you've made 2 classes.. This should work this way:

```
def exportMaterials(context):
    sel_mats = []
    for item in context.selected_ids:
    ... now context has something. your code here .... 

class SimpleTest(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "outliner.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "001"

    def execute(self, context):
        for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
            if area.type == 'OUTLINER':
                override = bpy.context.copy()
                override['area'] = area
                override["display_mode"] = ['LIBRARIES']
                exportMaterials(override)
                break            
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

Comment: Thank you, after I run it I get this message:

NameError: name 'exportMaterials' is not defined

Comment: O, sorry, this function should be outside, or it should be run throught self `self.functionname(context)` and  `def main(self,context):`